# Appending data from another database

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm trying to add an age column to a database (junecustomers) using a DOB column from an existing database (customerdata).

I have a matching firstname, lastname, and customerid column in both data sets. In the customerdata data set, I have the DOB column that I want to use to calculate the age. Is this correct?

```
select * from junecustomers
left join customerdata
on junecustomers.customerid = customerdata.customerid

alter table (junecustomers)
add select 

trunc(months_between(sysdate, dob)/12) Age from customerdata
```

Note: the customerdata database has multiple entries for some of the customers but the junecustomers database has only one entry per customer.

Comment: did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run two scripts, one to add the column and one to update the data, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE junecustomers
ADD COLUMN age INT;

UPDATE junecustomers jc
SET jc.age = (SELECT trunc(months_between(sysdate, dob)/12) FROM customerdata
WHERE customerid = jc.customerid LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: It depends on how you want to get the `age` field populated. Currently, it will round the age to number of years. If that's fine then yes, it looks good.